# ElasticSearch test http client

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic4s

My application should start an es server, I mean a local node, in the tests. The client should be a HttpClient.

```
val clusterName: String = "getting-started-with-elastic4s"
val homePath: Path = Files.createTempDirectory(clusterName)
val localNode = LocalNode(clusterName,homePath.toAbsolutePath.toString)
localNode.start()
val client = HttpClient(ElasticsearchClientUri("localhost",9200))
client.execute{
  createIndex("trial")
}.await
```

It gets timeout. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee that the port is going to be 9200. It *usually* is but perhaps something else has taken that port. You should generate the http client from the local node itself.

```
  val clusterName = "getting-started-with-elastic4s"
  val homePath = Files.createTempDirectory(clusterName)
  val localNode = LocalNode(clusterName, homePath.toAbsolutePath.toString)
  localNode.start()

  val client = localNode.http(true)
  val resp = client.execute {
    createIndex("trial")
  }.await
  println(resp)
```

Comment: I am using 5.5. This http call is in 6.0 I guess

Comment: Should be in 5.5 too.